# Уровни наследования в PHP?

Tags: php, ооп

Множественного наследования в PHP нет (ну в классическом понимании), множественное это когда унаследуются от несколькоих классов сразу. Сегодня встретил конструкцию типа:

```
$this->parent->parent->nameMethod()
```

Очевидно класс в котром я нахожусь чей-то наследник, а тот ещё чек-то наследник в свою очередь.

1) Ограничен ли уровень такого наследования в глубину?

2) Хороший ли это тон, правильная архитектура проекта допускает такое, или лучше ограничиться всегда одним уровнем?

Comment: $this->parent это не наследование, а обращение к объекту в поле parent и там может быть что угодно. Обращение к родителю это parent::nameMethod()

Comment: В данном случае `parent` - это локальная переменная

Comment: @rjhdby локальная переменная родителя? Почему их тогда две?

Comment: Конечно не родителя. Может там дерево какое и parent указывает на родительский узел и потому имеет такое имя. но к наследованию это не имеет отношения. А две их потому что nameMethod() лежит на 2 уровня от текущего объекта

Comment: стрелочки это [Fluent_interface](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) (хотя иногда называют цепочкой вызовов). Можешь пример с *PHP* посмотреть на странице

Answer (score 1):

1) В данном случае идет обращение к переменной экземпляра по имени `$parent`, а не к родительскому объекту.

Как правильно заметили, для обращение к методу родителя используется конструкция `parent::nameMethod()`

2) Это совершенно нормальная практика, которая используется повсеместно. Конкретно  про PHP на вскидку хороший пример в голову не приходит, поскольку ООП там не является определяющей язык парадигмой, а вот в той же Java развесистые кусты наследования сплошь и рядом.

Более того, многие считают практику строительства большого дерева наследования единственно верной в разрезе SOLID.

Например:

```
abstract class Animal{
    function die(){
        die();
    }
    abstract function move();
    abstract function say();
}

abstract class Bird extends Animal{
    abstract function say();
    function move(){
        fly();
    }
}

class Raven extends Bird{
    function say(){
        echo "КАР!!";
    }
}
```

Теперь у объекты класса Raven будут уметь летать через метод родителя `move()`, умирать через метод деда `die()` и каркать собственной реализацией метода `say()`